# Windows : can't generate libx264.dll because MinGW : no working c compiler found

Tags: windows, mingw, x264

It's my first post in a forum ever (and in english...) Any suggestion is welcomed.

So let's started !

My global goal is to recorder/transcoding and display an IP Camera stream from a .bat whitch calling vlc. (I tried before doing it with VLC interface and it's going well. I don't understand why the encoder is missing using that way)

I want an asf container containing h264 and aac.

---

.bat :

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC

vlc rtsp://root:root@ip_adresse/media.amp --sout "#transcode{ vcodec=x264, vb=112 , acodec==aac, fps=25}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=standard{access=file,mux = asf,dst=flux.asf}" -v

---

when I first execute this, VLC told me that H264 encoder was not found, so I decided to compile x264.

I used this link

http://www.ayobamiadewole.com/Blog/How-to-build-x264-or-libx264.dll-in-Windows

I succeed to make the .exe but and when I got to

./configure --disable-cli --enable-shared --extra-ldflags=-Wl,--output-def=libx264.def

minGW shell indicates : no working c compiler found

I find some answer, but i didn't found the good one.

Does anyone have an idea of what i'm doing wrong ?

Is it possible that my gcc (4.6) is not the good one ? What should I do ?

Need another advice :
**When I would have this libx264.ddl where should I put it to make my script working ?**

Early thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my question, I bypassed it.

By changing my script :

rtsp://root:root@ip_adresse/media.amp --sout "#transcode{ **vcodec=h264**, fps=25}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=standard{access=file,mux = asf,dst=flux.asf}" -v

I don't understand why VLC made me crazy about H264, telling me he didn't found H264 encoder and telling me it was not his fault... I forgive him (I know that it was MY fault)but i lost a lot of time on that crap...

If this can help anyone...

Otherwise if someone can help me to undersand what happened there it would be appreciated.

I can't wait to get some answer. ;-)